# Category of representations of a tensor product algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory

Given two semisimple unital algebras $A$ and $B$, defined over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, denote their categories of representations by $_A\mathcal{M}$ and $_B\mathcal{M}$ respectively. Can one describe the category of representations of $A \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} B$ as some type of "tensor product" of the categories $_A\mathcal{M}$ and $_B\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: Now posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Category of representations of a tensor product algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349711). When [meta-tag:cross-posting], it is recommended to link each of the copies to the other one. See, for example, [this answer on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088).